# wp_mail_from: different from address each time

Tags: wordpress

I have a form. Where user gives their name and email address. The I use the custom plugin to send the mail. The requirement is I need to send the mail on behalf of the user who signed.

Now in wp_mail how to achieve that?

I know about this filter: wp_mail_from. But how to call it every time wp_mail is called and set different from address?

Finally I also want to clear the wp_mail_from filter so that it doesn't affect the other forms.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_mail accepts "headers"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Using_.24headers_To_Set_.22From:.22.2C_.22Cc:.22_and_.22Bcc:.22_Parameters

```
<?php
  $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
  wp_mail('test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. So I should be using $headers = 'From:' . $name . $from_mail . "\r\n"; and pass the variables each time I call the function.

Comment: Make it `$headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <'. $from_mail . ">\r\n"; `